# initialize all the values in a javascript array to 0 without iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there any way to make javascript array to initialize all the values to 0 without iteration like as shown below

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

to

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could, in compliant browsers, use `Array.prototype.fill()`:

```
 var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 array.fill(0); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a magic function that doesn't (even internally) have to iterate over the loop? I...don't think that exists.

Comment: getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function http://jsfiddle.net/L6hj442e/

Comment: @Alex: which is why I clarified that it was "*in compliant browsers*", albeit I'd only had a chance to test in Chrome at that point (before work took me afk for a little while).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, since i cant use this because of browser compatibility

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0))
```

Useful article [Initializing arrays](http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/initializing-arrays.html)

Comment: if this answer solved your problem, you should approve it, maybe editing the question to setup the answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit tricky. But it works

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array).replace(/(\d+)/g,0)); // Returns [0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer....actually we are following clean code strategy ....so i cant use this stuffs

Answer (score 1):

i guess you don't need eval if you use JSON.parse() to build the empties and splice() to mutate the existing array instead of just making a new array full of zeros:

```
var r=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

[].splice.apply(r, 
   [0, r.length].concat( 
     JSON.parse("[0"+new Array(r.length).join(",0")+"]")  
));
alert(r); // shows: "0,0,0,0,0"
```

Answers based on map()/fill() will not affect the orig array as desired, but those solutions could use splice like the above answer to do so, the only difference then is how one build the zero-filled array.

EDIT: kudos to Gilsha, i was working on an eval-based answer when you reminded me that JSON would be enough.